# Magento REST API: oauth_problem=signature_invalid

Tags: magento, oauth

Code below return an error message:

```
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":401,"message":"oauth_problem=signature_invalid"}]}}
```

Anyone know a solution? It happens when I create a product and try to assign it to a category.

```
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

//Creating the product here and straight after assiging it to a category

} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo '<br/>';
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176319/5888

Comment: @BentCoder did the post solve your problem? Thx

Comment: It was 3 years ago so I don't even remember what I have done with this. It was one-off Magento thing too.